# Unable to element id via $Component path

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Below is my sample code. I am getting null value for var x, in alert 2. The html version of the code is working perfectly fine on http://jsfiddle.net.

```
<apex:page id="tstpage">
<script>
 alert ('test1');
 var x = document.getElementById("{!$Component.tstpage.frm}");
 alert('x value ' +x);
</script> 

<apex:form id="frm">
   testing1
</apex:form>

  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
    This is your new Page
     <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
   </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This illustrates the problem where the element is only found in the "after" case:

```
<apex:page id="tstpage">

<script>
alert('before ' + document.getElementById("{!$Component.tstpage.frm}"));
</script> 

<apex:form id="frm">
testing1
</apex:form>

<script>
alert('after ' + document.getElementById("{!$Component.tstpage.frm}"));
</script> 

</apex:page>
```

The HTML elements (including the `script`ones) for the page are processed sequentially from top to bottom, so when the first script runs the form has not yet been added to the DOM. When the second script runs it has so the script can find it.

Comment: Much better than moving the script down on the page would be a proper page load listener.

Comment: @AdrianLarson AFAIK placing the JavaScript at the end of the page works just as well as adding the code to a ready listener and avoids the risk of overwriting code added by the platform. But would be interested in links to anything that argues the opposite.